# Issue with laravel and config variables

Tags: laravel

I am installing an Payment Getaway API and this says that I have to put in the .env this:

```
INSTAPAGO_KEY_ID = 74D4A278-C3F8-4D7A-9894-FA0571D7E023
INSTAPAGO_PUBLIC_KEY_ID = e9a5893e047b645fed12c82db877e05a
```

Then when I run the payment getaway to make the payment it shows this error:

```
The KeyId property is required.
```

The part of the code in the vendor folder of Laravel which has the error is this one:

```
namespace Socialgest\Instapago;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class Instapago
{
const API_HOST = 'https://api.instapago.com/';
const TIMEOUT = 20.0;

protected $api_url;
protected $key_id;
protected $public_key_id;
protected $client;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->key_id = config('instapago.key_id');
    $this->public_key_id = config('instapago.public_key_id');
    $this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => self::API_HOST,
        'timeout'  => self::TIMEOUT,
    ]);
}
```

How you can see, it is calling a config variable, I do not know where it comes, so I though that If I added in config/services.php like this:

```
return [

  'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
  ],

  'ses' => [
    'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
    'region' => env('SES_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
  ],

  'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
  ],

  'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
  ],

  'instapago' => [
    'key_id' => env('INSTAPAGO_KEY_ID'),
    'public_key_id' => env('INSTAPAGO_PUBLIC_KEY_ID'),
  ],
];
```

It would work, but I do not know why? it still does not find the KEY ID and it is in the .env so I woder what can the problem be?

Or how can I set the .env variables directly instead of config variable, I mean how can I add env('INSTAPAGO_KEY_ID')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try `config('services.instapago.key_id')` and `config('services.instapago.public_key_id')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to access `env()` variables in your code. You should be using the `config()` hierarchy as you have done. Make sure you reload the configuration cache before you run your program with

`php artisan config:cache`

If you are still having trouble, try using `php artisan tinker` and see if those variables are populated. NOTE: you can see `env()` variables in tinker, but you shouldn't use them in production code.

Answer (score -2):

since your variables have hyphens, you have to enclose them in ""

```
INSTAPAGO_KEY_ID = "74D4A278-C3F8-4D7A-9894-FA0571D7E023"
```

Comment: Hyphens don't require quotes. You do need quotes for spaces, though.